# Getting notification when HTTP Fails (Azure Logic App)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm new to Azure, i searched but didn't find something reliable for me.I have an azure app which is sending some HTTP requests to my API. Is there any chance to get an email notification if the HTTP request fails ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create an alert rule for your logic app, navigate to the logic app in the portal -> Alerts -> New alert rule. Specify the parameters, action group. You need to create a new [action group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/action-groups) first, use the `Action Type` with `Email/SMS/Push/Voice`, set the emails address, etc.

For more details, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-action-rules).

Comment: What i don't find is how to bind the action group to the HTTP action in the Azure Logic App

Comment: what's the action called and when can i put the condition " whent he HTTP fails etc " ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can take advantage of exceptional handling technique provided by the azure logic app 
Add a trigger after the HTTP call as you want to send email add send email action
Click on the setting  top right corner of the action 
Click on configure run after 
Select is failed or skipped 
So this action will only if the previous action is failed